# How to switch p:tab in the same form using a command button

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabview

How do I switch to a tab (`<p:tab>`) using a command button?

Answer (score 7):

There is also a client side api method called selectTab(index);

```
<p:commandButton type="button" onclick="widgetvar.selectTab(2)" value="Show" />
```

Comment: An anonymous user edit your post (that was rejected). But I thought the edit was worth adding as a comment: `Actually selectTab is depreciated..use select() instead`

Answer (score 2):

`p:tabView` has an attribute `activeIndex` that is the "Index of the active tab" (Primefaces Documentation).

You could set this attribute from the action method of your `p:commandButton`:

```
<p:commandButton value="Switch tab" action=#{myBean.switchTab} />
```

Define an action method switchTab() in your backing bean and let it set a member `activeTab`.

Then use this member to set your active tab

```
<p:tabView activeIndex=#{myBean.activeTab}>
```

If your server supports EL 2.2 you can set the index of the active tab with the action method call:

```
<p:commandButton value="Switch tab" action=#{myBean.switchTab(2)} />
```

Then you can use the argument of your action method call to set the active index directly.

Answer (score 0):

I use Primefaces 5.1 and what I did was bind my tabView in the ManagedBean and set the activeIndex there

In your JSF

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="form">
    <p:tabView id="tabPanel" widgetVar="tabPanel" binding="#{managedBean.tabView}" dynamic="true">
        <p:tab title="tab" >
        <p:commandButton action="#{managedBean.getBla}"
              icon="ui-icon-search" update=":form:tabPanel" immediate="true" >
              ...
```

In your ManagedBean

```
private TabView tabView;
public TabView getTabView() {
    return tabView;
}

public void setTabView(TabView tabView) {
  this.tabView = tabView;
```

}

And then in the method you call in your commandButton action you just do a 
    `tabView.setActiveIndex(1);`

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

To switch p:tab in the same form using a command button
At the Client side only you can use widgetVar to select/view tab as follow:

**Note: tabIndex will start from 0 for the first tab.**

```
<p:commandButton type="button" onclick="PF('tabWidgetVar').select(1)" value="Next" />
```

At the server side you can bind a integer variable with the activeIndex property of the p:tab and then excute method to set index.

Comment: Why you added duplicate answer years later?